# Failed opening required helpers.php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel application in 000WebHost (with PHP 8.0). However I'm getting the next error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/storage/ssd5/191/19896191/laravel/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/helpers.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd5/191/19896191/laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd5/191/19896191/laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(43): {closure}() #1 /storage/ssd5/191/19896191/laravel/vendor/autoload.php(25): ComposerAutoloaderInit77107db52e33f59325c65f41516f3a02::getLoader() #2 /storage/ssd5/191/19896191/public_html/index.php(36): require('...') #3 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd5/191/19896191/laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 39

[image: error]

To see the error I added this in the beginning of my index.php:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

To upload the project, I do the next steps:

1. I compress all the files except the folder public, and the folder public separated.

[image: folders]

2. Extract them in the hosting folder with [unzipper](https://github.com/ndeet/unzipper).
   The resultant file structure is:

[image: folder structure]

3. Make changes in `index.php`
   I added "laravel/" in this two lines

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

4. Make changes in `app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function register()
{
  $this->app->bind('path.public',function(){
  return'/public_html';
  });
}
```

5. Clear cache

I remove all files in `bootstrap/cache` except for `.gitignore`

I also have tried running this commands before compress the files:

- composer install
- composer dump-autoload
- composer update
- composer update --no-scripts

6. Configuring properly my .env (database, etc)

The only change I manually made in my composer.json was to add this line:

```
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "platform-check": false, //This line!
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
```

I also have tried changing my `.htaccess` to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And using a different structure in my folders

Comment: why are you changing the .htaccess file and adding ``laravel`` in index.php file?

Comment: Changing .htaccess was just because I had read it, just for trying. And adding laravel is because if you see my folder structure you will see that my bootstrap and vendor folders are in a "laravel" folder, while my public_html is outside it. I've also tried puting all in the same folder without adding laravel in index.php.

Comment: So.. your public directory is actually public_html. That's the only difference. Try to solve that problem, use this gist: https://gist.github.com/johanvanhelden/29096a9ff31eac9b039d36056919abbb#file-reconfigure-laravel-instructions-md. Your actual error *most likely* has something to do with your autoloader. We usually run `composer dump-autoload -o`, but that would be impossible on your host. Make public_html working on your local environment, re-zip everything and try again